# Difference between DeferedResult and CompletableFeature

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, api, asynchronous

I've been developing Rest API's in Java. I want to convert them it into Async. The Two options I see is DeferredResult and CompletableFeature.

I don't seem to be find the difference between these two, and when to chose over another.

Any real time examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

`DeferredResult` is **spring** class and it is just a container of the result (as its name implies) so we need to explicitly use some kind of thread pool (ForkJoinPool for example) to run our processing asynchronously. `CompletableFuture` is part of `java.util.concurrent` and allow to run the processing asynchronously. It implements `Future` and basically have the ability to compose, combine and execute asynchronous computation steps.

Simple example of both options:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/deferredResult")
public DeferredResult<Boolean> useDeferredResult() {
    DeferredResult<Boolean> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
    deferredResult.onCompletion(() -> logResult((Boolean)deferredResult.getResult()));
    ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(() -> {
        deferredResult.setResult(processRequest());
    });
    return deferredResult;
}

@GetMapping(value = "/completableFuture")
public CompletableFuture<Boolean> useCompletableFuture() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::processRequest)
            .thenApplyAsync(this::logResult);
}

private boolean logResult(Boolean result) {
    System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    return true;
}

private boolean processRequest() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Notes:

- By default, Spring will execute the `CompletableFuture` actions by
  `ForkJoinPool` (can be configured).
- In the case of `DeferredResult`, the `logResult` will be executed by the servlet container (for example Tomcat) worker thread - not nessecrally the one got the request at the beginning.
- You can (while I don't see any
  reason to) run processing asynchronously with `CompletableFuture` and
  return `DeferredResult`.
- With `DeferredResult` you can register more callbacks, like  `onCompleted` - For example `onError`, etc. [See here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html).
- `CompletableFuture` has a lot options to compose actions. [See here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html).

IMHO, `CompletableFuture` is more elegant and has more capabilities.

Also, [here](https://github.com/elirandav/springAsyncServlet/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/springAsyncServlet/DeferredResultVsCompletableController.java) you have a working example project.